# How to fix "No FileSystem for scheme: gs" in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read a json file from a google bucket into a pyspark dataframe on a local spark machine.  Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '16g'),
                        ('spark.executor.cores','4'),
                         ('spark.cores.max','4')]).setMaster('local[*]')


spark = (SparkSession.
              builder.
              config(conf=conf).
              getOrCreate())


sc = spark.sparkContext

import glob
import bz2
import json
import pickle


bucket_path = "gs://<SOME_PATH>/"
client = storage.Client(project='<SOME_PROJECT>')
bucket = client.get_bucket ('<SOME_PATH>')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

theframes = []

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)        
    testspark = spark.read.json(bucket_path + blob.name).cache()
    theframes.append(testspark)
```

It's reading files from the bucket fine (I can see the print out from blob.name), but then crashes like this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test_code.py", line 66, in <module>
   testspark = spark.read.json(bucket_path + blob.name).cache()
 File "/home/anaconda3/envs/py37base/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 274, in json
return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
 File "/home/anaconda3/envs/py37base/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
 File "/home/anaconda3/envs/py37base/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
 File "/home/anaconda3/envs/py37base/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

I've seen this type of error discussed on stackoverflow, but most solutions seem to be in Scala while I have pyspark, and/or involve messing with core-site.xml, which I've done to no effect.

I am using spark 2.4.1 and python 3.6.7.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some config params are required to recognize "gs" as a distributed filesystem.

Use this setting for google cloud storage connector, gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config("spark.jars", "/path/to/gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Other configs that can be set from pyspark

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.impl', 'com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem')
# This is required if you are using service account and set true, 
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable', 'true')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile', "/path/to/keyfile")
# Following are required if you are using oAuth
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.client.id', 'YOUR_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID')
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.gs.auth.client.secret', 'OAUTH_SECRET')
```

Alternatively you can set up these configs in core-site.xml or spark-defaults.conf.

### Hadoop Configuration on Command Line

You can also use `spark.hadoop`-prefixed configuration properties to set things up when `pyspark` (or `spark-submit` in general), e.g.

```
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to [Ranga Vure](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3012093/ranga-vure)'s answer, concretely for spark and hadoop 3 you can do:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('spark-run-with-gcp-bucket') \
    .config("spark.jars", "https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-hadoop3-latest.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

This pulls the required jar file directly from google. You can find other versions on google's hadoop pages [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage), specifically under "Download the connector". You can copy the links to the connectors and put them inside the config instead of having to download them locally.

I then set another config:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True)
```

and am able to directly pull a CSV file from my GCP bucket with:

```
df = spark \
    .read \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .csv("gs://<BUCKET>/<FILE.csv>")
```

Note:
I have already set the following on my machine so authentication with gcp occurs properly:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "<PATH TO CREDENTIALS WITH PERMISSION TO VIEW BUCKET OBJECT>"
```