# Py4JJavaError in google colab

Tags: pyspark, storage, google-colaboratory

```
Py4JJavaError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-013b1902bcdc> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df=spark.read.parquet("gs://tata_2/activityObf.parquet")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o527.parquet.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark error: : java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595263/pyspark-error-java-io-ioexception-no-filesystem-for-scheme-gs)